# Why converting npy files (containing video frames) to tfrecords consumes too much disk space?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, protocol-buffers, tfrecord

I am working on a violence detection service. I am trying to develop software based on the code in [this repo](https://github.com/mchengny/RWF2000-Video-Database-for-Violence-Detection/blob/master/Networks/Flow%20Gated%20Network.ipynb). [My dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/shreyj1729/cctv-fights-dataset) consists of videos resided in two directories "Violence" and "Non-Violence".

I used [this code](https://github.com/mchengny/RWF2000-Video-Database-for-Violence-Detection/blob/master/Preprocess/Video2Numpy.ipynb) to generate `npy` files out of **RGB channels and optical flow features**. The output of this part would be 2 folders containing `npy` array **with `244x244x5` shape**. (`np.float32` dtype). so it's like I have video frames in RGB in the first 3 channels (`npy[...,:3]`) and optical flow features in the next two channels (`npy[..., 3:]`).

Now I am trying to **convert them to `tfrecords`** and use `tf.data.tfrecorddataset` to speed up the training process. Since my model input has to be a **cube tensor**, my **training elements** has to be **64 frames** of each video. **It means the data point shape has to be `64x244x244x5`**.

So I used this code to convert the npy files to tfrecords.

```
from pathlib import Path
from os.path import join
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import cv2
from tqdm import tqdm


def normalize(data):
    mean = np.mean(data)
    std = np.std(data)
    return (data - mean) / std


def random_flip(video, prob):
    s = np.random.rand()
    if s < prob:
        video = np.flip(m=video, axis=2)
    return video


def color_jitter(video):
    # range of s-component: 0-1
    # range of v component: 0-255
    s_jitter = np.random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2)
    v_jitter = np.random.uniform(-30, 30)
    for i in range(len(video)):
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(video[i], cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
        s = hsv[..., 1] + s_jitter
        v = hsv[..., 2] + v_jitter
        s[s < 0] = 0
        s[s > 1] = 1
        v[v < 0] = 0
        v[v > 255] = 255
        hsv[..., 1] = s
        hsv[..., 2] = v
        video[i] = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)
    return video


def uniform_sample(video: str, target_frames: int = 64) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    gets video and outputs n_frames number of frames in video.
    Args:
        video:
        target_frames:

    Returns:

    """

    len_frames = int(len(data))
    interval = int(np.ceil(len_frames / target_frames))
    # init empty list for sampled video and
    sampled_video = []
    for i in range(0, len_frames, interval):
        sampled_video.append(video[i])
        # calculate number of padded frames and fix it
    num_pad = target_frames - len(sampled_video)
    if num_pad > 0:
        padding = [video[i] for i in range(-num_pad, 0)]
        sampled_video += padding

    return np.array(sampled_video, dtype=np.float32)


def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = Path('transformed/')
    npy_files = list(path.rglob('*.npy'))[:100]
    aug = True
    # one_hots = to_categorical(range(2), dtype=np.int8)
    path_to_save = 'data_tfrecords'
    tfrecord_path = join(path_to_save, 'all_data.tfrecord')

    with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecord_path) as writer:

        for file in tqdm(npy_files, desc='files converted'):
            # load npy files
            npy = np.load(file.as_posix(), mmap_mode='r')
            data = np.float32(npy)
            del npy

            # Uniform sampling
            data = uniform_sample(data, target_frames=64)
            # Add augmentation
            if aug:
                data[..., :3] = color_jitter(data[..., :3])
                data = random_flip(data, prob=0.5)

            # Normalization
            data[..., :3] = normalize(data[..., :3])
            data[..., 3:] = normalize(data[..., 3:])
            # Label one hot encoding
            label = 1 if file.parent.stem.startswith('F') else 0
            # label = one_hots[label]

            feature = {'image': _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(data.tobytes())),
                       'label': _int64_feature(int(label))}
            example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))

            writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

The code works fine, but the **real problem** is that it **consumes too much disk drive**. my whole dataset consisting of 2000 videos takes 12 GB, when I converted them to npy files, it became around 80 GB, and now **using tfrecords** It became **over 120 GB** or so. How can I convert them in an **efficient way to reduce the space required to store them**?

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be too late. But I see you are still saving the video frame in your tfrecords file.
Try removing the "image" feature from your features list. And saving per frame as their Height, Width, Channels, and so forth.

```
feature = {'label': _int64_feature(int(label))}
```

Which is why the file is taking more space.